# how to merge two two objects with different depths dynamically

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

I have two identical objects with me

```
let a  = {
  title : "developer”,
  startDate:{ month :’jan’}
}

let b  = {
  title :{
    value: ""
  } ,
startDate :{month:{value:””}}
}
```

i need to merge dynamically these two to get object like below

```
let c  = {
  title :{
    value: "developer"
  } ,
startDate:{
  month:{ value:” jan”}}
}
```

Comment: I don't wanna be "that guy" but I think you probably need to start by making both object have the same structure, before attempting to run a deep merge

Comment: these objects are not identical. Could you provide some other rules or explain your idea deeply.

Comment: i will simplify

lets consider below object
let a  = {
  title : "developer”,
  startDate:{ month :’jan’}
}

need to traverse till last property and
assign last value to new property "value"  .
like below
 a  = {
  title :{
    value: "developer"
  } ,
startDate:{
  month:{ value:” jan”}}
}

Comment: Would a custom code be helpful ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't require object `b` because it's just a replica of object `a` with extra 'value' property.
You can traverse the complete `a` object and then deep copy the value in the `b` object.

I wrote a recursive method for this where you can traverse to the last level of the object and copy the value in another object.

```js
function mergeObj(sourceObj, newObj) {

  Object.keys(sourceObj).forEach(key => {
    if (sourceObj[key] && typeof sourceObj[key] === 'object') {
      newObj[key] = {};
      mergeObj(sourceObj[key], newObj[key]);
    } else {
      // updating properties
      newObj[key] = {};
      newObj[key]['value'] = sourceObj[key];
    }
  });
}

let a  = {
  title : "developer",
  startDate:{ month :'jan'}
};
let b  = {};

mergeObj(a,b);

console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to start by making both object have the same structure, and then run the deep merge. [lodash's merge](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#merge) can help you with it

```
const newA = Object.entries(a).reduce((newObject, [key, value]) => ({
  ...newObject,
  [key]: { value },
}, {}))

// newA looks now like
//
// {
//   title: {
//     value: "developer
//   }
// }

let c = _.merge(a, b);  // lodash merge for deep merge. Otherwise write your own
```

Comment: I can't use third party libraries

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround for your problem:

```
    let a  = {
      title : "developer",
      startDate:{ month :'jan'}
    }

    let b  = {
      title :{
        value: ''
      } ,
      startDate :{month:{value:''}}
    }
    var c = {}; 
    c.startDate = {}; 
    c.title = {};
    c.startDate.month = {}; 
    c.startDate.month.value = a.startDate.month; 
    c.title.value = a.title;
    
    console.log("Merged object",c);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just implement a function that does this for you. Given your example:

```
let a  = {
  title: "developer",
  startDate: { month: "jan" }
};

let b  = {
  title: {
    value: ""
  },
  startDate: { month: { value: "" }}
};
```

You can use this to get the values:

```
const mergeObject = (a, b) => {
  b.title.value = a.title;
  b.startDate.month.value = a.startDate.month;

  return b;
};
```

If you call now say `let c = mergeObject(a, b)` c will be

```
let c  = {
  title: {
    value: "developer"
  },
  startDate: {
  month: { value: "jan" }}
}
```

Of course this function can be modified to reflect your exact needs.